# Сложное условие в Excel

Tags: excel

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как составить формулу для выполнения условия: если значение ячейки меньше 90, то результат равен А, если больше 90, но меньше 180, то - В, если больше 180, но меньше 270, то С, иначе - D.

Пробовал формулу
`=ЕСЛИ(А1<90;"А";ЕСЛИ(А1>270;"D"))` - но это только для крайних условий
Быть может, можнов условии использовать логические операторы И, ИЛИ, и тд?

Answer (score 5):

Так как нижние граничные условия проверяются в предыдущих функциях, некоторые проверки можно убрать. Если число не нужно показывать текстом, кавычки тоже лишние:

```
=ЕСЛИ(A2<90;1;ЕСЛИ(A2<180;2;ЕСЛИ(A2<270;3;4)))
```

Варианты:

```
=ПРОСМОТР(A2;{0;90;180;270};{1;2;3;4})
=ВПР(A2;{0;1:90;2:180;3:270;4};2;1)
```

Похоже, рассматриваются секторы круга и больше 360 не будет.
В таком случае можно:

```
=ВЫБОР(A2/90+1;1;2;3;4;4)
=МИН(ЦЕЛОЕ(A2/90)+1;4)
```

Работа ВПР с диапазоном констант описана здесь:

[применение диапазона констант в функции ВПР](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/617968/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%92%D0%9F%D0%A0)

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как составить формулу для выполнения условия: если значение ячейки от 1-3, то результат равен 1,5%, если от 4-6, то 2%, если от 7-10, то 3%, и если от 10 и больше то 4%.

Answer (score 2):

Уже сообразил

```
=ЕСЛИ(И(А2>=0;А2<90);"1";ЕСЛИ(И(А2>=90;А2<180);"2";ЕСЛИ(И(А2>=180;А2<270);"3";"4")))
```

Comment: alexnik, читайте предыдущий ответ: в Вашей формуле лишние проверки, можно оптимизировать.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Пригодилась и очень (;