# Объяснить применение диапазона в функции ВПР

Tags: excel

В [Сложное условие в Excel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/146424/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-excel)
есть формула `=ВПР(A2;{0;1:90;2:180;3:270;4};2;1)`.
Но она у меня не работает и я не могу понять ее исходя из представления и описания функции.
Можете помочь разобраться?

Comment: "Не работает" это выдаёт ошибку? Выдаёт неправильный результат? Что именно? Кроме того, что вы сами знаете о работе функции ВПР, какой её минимальный вид, что где нужно прописать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

О *ВПР* должно быть понятно:

```
 =ВПР(что_ищем;где_ищем;здесь_нужное;ИСТИНА)
```

Ищем значение *что_ищем* в диапазоне *где_ищем*, при обнаружении показываем значение нужного столбца *здесь_нужное*. Последний параметр указывает на то, как искать значение - по точному (*ЛОЖЬ, 0*) или неточному (*ИСТИНА, 1*) совпадению.

В *Excel* можно указывать диапазон констант. Для этого набор постоянных величин заключается в фигурные скобки, разделителем между ними можеет служить ":"(разделитель строк) или ";" (разделитель столбцов).

```
=ВПР(A2;{0;1:90;2:180;3:270;4};2;1)
```

Прочитаем формулу: найти неточное совпадение (последний параметр - 1) значения ячейки *A2* в диапазоне констант и показать значение второго столбца.
Визульно диапазон констант этой формулы можно представить в ячейках  листа:

[image: диапазон]

===========================
Примеры.

*A2 = 90*

Ищем 90. Нашли во второй строке, посмотрели во второй столбец - имеем результат 2.

*A2 = 92*

Ищем 92, Во второй строке 90... идем дальше... 180. Но это >92. Возвращаемся на строку ниже, смотрим во второй столбец - имеем результат 2.

При неточном совпадении находим значение, равное искомому или наибольшее из меньших. Если указать точный поиск, формула при поиске числа 92 покажет #Н/Д - нет такого в диапазоне.

*A2 = 500*

Максимальное значение в диапазоне 270, оно же - наибольшее среди меньших. В этом случае результат - 4

Comment: Спасибо ОГРОМНОЕ - Вы мне очень помогли. Не хватало данных о константах!

Comment: @ЕвгенийАнатольевич Отметьте ответ как принятый (зелёная галочка слева от ответа), раз он вам помог.